# Delta function derivation

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

can someone guide me to solve this equation. i thought of going about it by splitting the limits and then integration by parts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYHt1.png)

Comment: It's simpler than that. You are looking at something like $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} n f(x) dx$. The point is that if $n$ is large, $x$ is in the interval $[-1/n,1/n]$, and $f$ is "nice", then $f(x)$ is close to $f(0)$.

Comment: Sorry, minor error: it'd be something like $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} \frac{n}{2} f(x) dx$.